# Find to list all files with date pattern to tar them together

Tags: find, tar

I have a directory with many log files, with filenames like `acct.20111001` up to `acct.20111030`.  I want to zip them by running:

```
tar -cvjf acct.20111001.bz2 acct.20111001
```

How can I use `find` to compress them instead of running the `tar` command for each and every file?

I'm thinking something like this, but I know this command doesn't work:

```
find /home/log/2011/10 -name "acct.201110[0-9]" -exec tar -cvjf {}.bz2 {} \;
```

Comment: Why bother with tar if you're only putting one source file in each archive. Just....find /home/log/2011/10 -name "acct.201110[0-9]" -exec bzip2 {};   and tarring the compressed files, although slightly less efficient than compressing the archive is more robust.

Comment: @symcbean `bzip2` can be useful, but its usage does not solve the *main* problem here - the files are not matched properly!

Answer (score 5):

The regular expression you've used with `find` does not match all files in the range `acct.20111001` to `acct.20111030`, because **you forgot about the last digit**.
If it's OK for you to match also `acct.20111000` (in case it exists, which I doubt judging from the date-look of the names), you can use

```
find /home/log/2011/10 -name "acct.201110[0-3][0-9]" -exec tar -cvjf {}.bz2 {} \;
```

Another option, especially when you have few files to operate on (less than hundreds) is not to use `find`, but a simple **`for`** loop instead. You can then make use of **range expression** that results in a list of zero-padded numbers:

```
 for file in acct.201110{01..30}; do tar -cvjf $file.bz2 $file; done
```

Yet Another option is possible if `acct.20111001` through `acct.20111030` are *the only files that begin with `acct.201110`* (which, again, I suspect to be the case) - then you can just use `acct.201110*` with any of the above mentioned commands.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
for file in acct.201110[0-9]; do tar -cvjf $file.bz2 $file; done
```

should work (maybe with a better glob to catch all days), but your problem sounds like [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) or [Newsyslog](http://www.weird.com/~woods/projects/newsyslog.html) is what you could need.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want for this is [cpio(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpio).  This will take a list of files from stdin and produce an archive.  If you need to produce an archive in tar format, use the `-H tar` option.

Comment: It is not what the OP asked for. He asked for a command to compress each file separately.

Comment: If that's the case I would agree with symcbean's comment - why not just use bzip2 directly.

Comment: Yes, one can (it will remove the original files by default), but that does not show the reason why OP's command did not work.

Comment: +1 since, as it turns out, it appears the user may intend to compress them all into one archive.  the users intent is to save space.  Also, read this:  http://rightsock.com/~kjw/Ramblings/tar_v_cpio.html